# Why is this angular directive lagging before it loads?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have isolated it to the use of `templateUrl` (when I use template with an injected string, it's instant) however I can't understand for the life of me why the `$templateCache` isn't working properly.

**AngularJS 1.2.16**

**The directive, for reference (THIS WORKS):**

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<ul class=\"custom-dropdown\">\n <li class=\"row\" ng-repeat=\"item in data\">\n     <div class=\"col-sm-3\">\n          <i class=\"{{ item.icon }}\"></i>\n     </div>\n        <div class=\"col-sm-9\">\n          <h2>{{ item.label }}</h2>\n         <p>{{ item.description }}</p>\n     </div>\n    </li>\n</ul>',
    scope: {
        model: '=ngMenuModel',
        data: '=ngSource',
        select: '&ngSelect'
    },
    compile: function(el, attrs, ctrl) {

        // Build Wrapper
        var container = angular.element('<div class="wrap-dd-menu"></div>'),
            button    = el.clone().empty(),
            template  = el.find('ul.dropdown');

        // Linker
        return function($scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
            // Compile Template
            var label = $scope.model.label || $scope.data[0].label || attrs.ngMenuDefault + ' <span class="caret"></span>' || '(choose one) <span class="caret"></span>';
            $compile(template)($scope);
            container.append(button.html(label));
            container.append(template);
            el.replaceWith(container);

        }
    }
};
```

[image]

**When I use `templateUrl` instead of `template`, it fails to load instantly**

```
...
templateUrl: 'my-template.ng.html',
...
```

[image]

**EXCEPT, I have this at the top of my JS declarations:**

```
angular.module('Template', []).run(function($templateCache){ 
    ... 
    $templateCache.put('my-template.ng.html', '... template html here... ');
    ...
```

And of course, *the module is being properly loaded into the main project (as the first dependency, even).*

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['Template', ...])...
```

**Last but not least, the HTML in question**

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-menu ng-menu-default="(choose one)" ng-menu-model="job.model.lead.type" ng-source="category.services">(choose one) <span class="caret"></span></button>
```

I even tried putting default HTML in there as a placeholder, however it seems as though as soon as Angular initializes, any directive using a templateUrl is instantly cleared (I have no way of appending content during the compile phase either that renders the content before I see a flash of the empty button).

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening, or what I can do to resolve it?  Thank you!!

**[Edit] -- Continued Debugging --**

I have isolated the issue to the way the `$templateCache` is loaded in the MAIN app module.

1. $templateCache.get('my-template.ng.html') === undefined
2. $templateCache issues a GET request to /my-template.ng.html
3. GET request fails (it's a custom 404 page though, so a 200 response)
4. $templateCache eventually loads from the module `Templates` confirmed by `$templateCache.get('my-template.ng.html')` after a 10s timeout.

This is incredibly strange because it is the very first dependency in that app/module, and I know for a fact that no synchronous HTTP calls are interrupting anything (due to the use of a single API factory endpoint).

To recap, **template DOES load from module, but only after `$templateCache` issues an HTTP request which returns a response, after which the CACHED version loads properly**

Comment: Does you main module depend on your `Template` module? If nothing depends on it then it won't be loaded and the `run` function won't.. well, run.

Comment: @ivarni yes it is, it is the first dependency

Comment: does it still load with a delay or not load at all?

Comment: @KhanhTO It does still load, but it takes ~1s and it's visually noticeable.  I could always add in a loading state, but it would be much less hack-ish solution if I could figure out how to make this work properly.

Comment: I'm not sure if you want ng-cloak: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: I just tested/verified my hunch, but ng-cloak will not work in this case as the element IS being included immediately, it simply has to do with the fact that it's recompiled to be nested inside a parent (not using transclude or replace).

Comment: Well, this *should* work. I've done it before. I know that doesn't help you much, but I would try to figure out why it's not working before looking at ngCloak or spinners. Can you verify that the code that populates the `$templateCache` gets executed? I'm pretty sure it does but I am a fan at looking for the obvious errors first.

Comment: @ivarni It is getting run--I verified that, as well as every step of the gulp build stream which is working properly (all compiled output tested/validated).  Perhaps something weird is going on, or I'm just missing a basic construct of the library... I'll have a jsfiddle in a few minutes if that helps (also, THANK YOU for taking the time)

Comment: Well, this works: http://plnkr.co/edit/DrPkmwo7LrT0wJWo7cra?p=preview and it's pretty much the same concept you're trying to do so there's got to be something silly somewhere that is going wrong.

Comment: @ivarni this keeps getting stranger--something else in the app is causing it to lag (some synchronous call?) because I was just able to load this fairly instantly as well (an exact demo): http://jsfiddle.net/G73Wx/

Comment: Well there you go, knowing the problem is half the battle. You could try to use your browsers dev-tools to find the culprit. And also double-check that there is not HTTP request for the template. It will show up in network traffic if there is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56027/discussion-between-julian-and-ivarni).

Comment: @Julian: Why don't you post a reproducing fiddle ? Also, did you try using the latest AngularJS version ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem my fiddle is in the comment above, but I will add it to the main question.  The problem is that it isn't actually able to reproduce the issue which seems to arise from another service provider or config routine (non-$http) that is blocking the immediate resolution of the cache and causing an extraneous (and erroneous) HTTP request to retrieve the template... **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/G73Wx/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it!

As it turns out, the issue *was* on my end, though it's worth noting that Angular not throwing any errors may confuse someone else in a similar situation.

First, **the cause** was really with the gulp build, as a mutator plugin ended up duplicating the module declaration in the final compiled output.

---

So, instead of the proper declaration, this was happening:

```
angular.module('Template', []).run(function($templateCache){ ... }), angular.module('Template', []).run(function($templateCache) { ... });
```

It initially went undetected due to `mangle` being used, but **interestingly angular threw no errors at runtime as of v1.2.16**

The module was still included in my main app, and was fully accessible, but the $templateCache provider must have been affected by the duplication as it fails to properly resolve whenever these duplicate declarations are present.

---

**[EDIT]** One more piece of advice I would like to provide to anyone creating a directive that modifies both the parent and child elements using $compile instead of transclude/replace:

**templateUrl will NOT work properly**

Despite the `template = $compile(template)($scope)` call in my linker, the scope was in fact not being bound (as evidenced by the fact that the `ng-repeat` loading off the local scope was empty while the model returned the proper values).

I ultimately resolved this by *removing `templateUrl` entirely* and changing my directive structure to this:

```
SR.directive('ngMenu', ['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {

    var template = $templateCache.get('/job-type.ng.html');

    // Runs during compile
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    //template: '<ul class=\"dropdown\">\n  <li class=\"row\" ng-repeat=\"item in data\">\n     <div class=\"col-sm-3\">\n          <i class=\"{{ item.icon }}\"></i>\n     </div>\n        <div class=\"col-sm-9\">\n          <h2>{{ item.label }}</h2>\n         <p>{{ item.description }}</p>\n     </div>\n    </li>\n</ul>',
    //templateUrl: '/job-type.ng.html',
    scope: {
        model: '=ngMenuModel',
        data: '=ngSource',
        select: '&ngSelect'
    },
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for following up and posting your solution Julian

Comment: Good job solving it :)

Comment: Apparently the not throwing an error-bit is by design. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1779. There's some discussion there, seems more people than you have been burned by accidentally declaring a module twice.